# Which technology is used in majority of LOB applications?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, silverlight, line-of-business-app

Which technology has the most market share among the line-of-business applications. Is it ASP.NET? Silverlight? WPF? Java? Or something else?

Comment: Can anyone authoritatively answer this question?  Perhaps you need to search the web for any independent market research on the subject.  That is of course outside of Jays answer which I'm sure is very true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Excel. Seriously.